# Can i use a partition formatted as NTFS (HDD) for my data and install Ubuntu on SSD?

Tags: software-installation, hard-drive, ssd, ntfs

I have a SSD (256 GB) and a HDD (1 TB). I currently keep my data in D: which is full HDD space and i keep windows 10 in C: which is all SSD space. I want to install Ubuntu on my SSD and keep the HDD with all it's files. Can i mount HDD if is formatted as NTFS after i install Ubuntu on my SSD. And also it is ok to keep it that way or will I occur some problems?

Comment: Yes, you can, why not? You'll need to disable Windows Fast Start feature to have read/write access from Linux.

Comment: But I don't want to keep it as dual boot, just format my SSD and install Ubuntu. Or i need to disable fast start before formatting?

Comment: If you won't have Windows, it is not a good idea to keep NTFS. Linux can use it, but can't maintain it well if any errors.

Comment: I understand. Thanks. So how can I move my data without brute force? Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Backup it somewhere else, then copy it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **you can use a NTFS partition to store data** and expect it to be problem free.

However, if you want put anything on a NTFS formatted volume that needs proper permissions or ownership to work properly, NTFS does not understand these concepts as they pertain to UNIX (which includes Ubuntu).